# Pig Error when trying to dump table

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to run a VERY simple pig script and keep running into complications.

SCRIPT:

```
log = LOAD 'C:/Users/malanio/Documents/test.log' USING PigStorage(',') AS (user:chararray, some:long, some2:chararray);
DUMP log;
```

The file I'm loading:

```
ravi,1,1
```

The following error occurs:

```
C:\Users\malanio\Documents>pig -x local testrun.pig
2014-06-12 14:46:22,939 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.12.1 (r1585011) compiled Apr 05 2014, 01:41:34
2014-06-12 14:46:22,940 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: C:\hadoop-2.4.0\logs\pig_1402598782937.log
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/pig-0.12.1/pig-0.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2014-06-12 14:46:23,616 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file C:\Users\malanio/.pigbootup not found
2014-06-12 14:46:23,702 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-06-12 14:46:23,702 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2014-06-12 14:46:23,704 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
2014-06-12 14:46:24,275 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2014-06-12 14:46:24,317 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NewPartitionFilterOptimizer, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier]}
2014-06-12 14:46:24,470 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2014-06-12 14:46:24,501 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2014-06-12 14:46:24,501 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2014-06-12 14:46:24,526 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2014-06-12 14:46:24,527 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2014-06-12 14:46:24,551 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl - falling back to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.20 ?)
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: runnerState
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1948)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.<clinit>(PigJobControl.java:51)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.newJobControl(HadoopShims.java:98)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:289)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:191)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1324)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1309)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:980)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:944)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:857)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:774)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:607)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
2014-06-12 14:46:24,569 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2014-06-12 14:46:24,579 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent
2014-06-12 14:46:24,581 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2014-06-12 14:46:24,584 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.compress is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress
2014-06-12 14:46:24,625 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2014-06-12 14:46:24,640 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2014-06-12 14:46:24,642 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cache
2014-06-12 14:46:24,645 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Distributed cache not supported or needed in local mode. Setting key [pig.schematuple.local.dir] with code temp directory: C:\Users\malanio\AppData\Local\Temp\1402598784640-0
2014-06-12 14:46:24,688 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2014-06-12 14:46:24,693 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address
2014-06-12 14:46:24,704 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2014-06-12 14:46:24,714 [JobControl] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl - Error while trying to run jobs.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:225)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:271)
2014-06-12 14:46:24,753 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2014-06-12 14:46:24,764 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2014-06-12 14:46:24,767 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job null has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2014-06-12 14:46:24,771 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2014-06-12 14:46:24,783 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backend error: Unexpected System Error Occured: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChang
eError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:225)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:271)

2014-06-12 14:46:24,821 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2014-06-12 14:46:24,824 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Detected Local mode. Stats reported below may be incomplete
2014-06-12 14:46:24,831 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
2.4.0   0.12.1  malanio 2014-06-12 14:46:24     2014-06-12 14:46:24     UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
N/A     log     MAP_ONLY        Message: Unexpected System Error Occured: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:225)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:271)
    file:/tmp/temp-590289635/tmp-804647280,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "C:/Users/malanio/Documents/test.log"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:/tmp/temp-590289635/tmp-804647280"

Job DAG:
null


2014-06-12 14:46:24,939 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2014-06-12 14:46:24,952 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias log
Details at logfile: C:\hadoop-2.4.0\logs\pig_1402598782937.log
```

When I comment out the DUMP line, there are no issues. It's only when the script is trying to dump the data that it runs into complications. I'm running the script locally on the latest hadoop(2.4.0) and the latest pig (0.12.1). I'm still new to pig, and there's probably a simple explanation to this, but I can't seem to decipher the error codes. I think it might have something to do with the pig jar and its API. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PIG - Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873050/pig-found-interface-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-jobcontext-but-class-was-expe)

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for check [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 1):

> When I comment out the DUMP line, there are no issues. It's only when the script is trying to dump the data that it runs into complications.

Statements in a pig script are not executed unless they are needed in the end result/output. That is why there is no issue with out the 'DUMP' statement. This is similar to lazy evaluation, but there is a difference.