# Pig script for frequency of books published each year

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to run the pig script by following the steps given on this link- http://www.orzota.com/pig-tutorialfor-beginners/

But I am getting this error.It is not able to read the file loaded into HDFS.
Can you please help? The error is as follows-

```
Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
N/A BookXRecords,CountByYear,GroupByYear    GROUP_BY,COMBINER   Message: Unexpected System Error Occured: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:225)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:271)
    /user/hduser/output/pig_output_bookx,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/user/hduser/input/BX-BooksCorrected1.txt"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "/user/hduser/output/pig_output_bookx"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
null


2015-02-19 22:19:45,852 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873050/pig-found-interface-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-jobcontext-but-class-was-expe

Comment: I am using hadoop-2.5.0 and pig-0.13.0 versions.I tried running pig script again for these version,it is giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you have just downloaded the script and run. That is the reason why your the script is not able to find the exact file you want to run the pig script on. Please ensure:

1. You have run sed command to filter the books.csv file on your local system
2. Name the filtered file which you have mentioned in the script get after running the sed (Not sure what's in your case but it should be `BX-BooksCorrected` or `BX-BooksCorrected1`, please check)
3. Then move that file into HDFS and then try running the script it will work and wont give the error

P.S.: You get to know the nature of the error by carefully reading the error log. Happy Hadooping!