# ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I am new to hadoop. I was trying to integrate PIG with hive using Hcatalog but getting the below error during dump. Please let me know if any of you can help me out:

```
A = load 'logs' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
dump A
```

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled
>   internal error.

Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

load and describe work fines but dump gives above error

Details:
   hadoop-2.6.0
   pig-0.14.0
   hive-0.12.0

Compiled piggybank using

```
   $ "ant -Dhadoopversion=23 clean jar"

     export PIG_OPTS=-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:10000
     export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HCAT_HOME/share/hcatalog/*:$HIVE_HOME/lib/*


$ REGISTER     hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar;

$ REGISTER    hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar;

$ REGISTER     hive-0.12.0/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hcatalog-core-0.12.0.jar;

$ REGISTER     hive-0.12.0/lib/hive-exec-0.12.0.jar;

$ REGISTER     hive-0.12.0/lib/hive-metastore-0.12.0.jar;
```

ran hive server using `"hive --service hiveserver"`

```
   hive-site.xml:(and mysql related stuff )
   hive.metastore.local
     true
```

Please let me know if anything else needs to be configured

Comment: From the deleted answer: this question may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873050/pig-found-interface-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-jobcontext-but-class-was-expe